# Limit the number/width of LI "Christmas Lights"?

Tags: html, css

I'm using this Christmas Lights CSS code:
https://codepen.io/tobyj/pen/QjvEex

The code works by using a single `<li></li>` to display one "light".

Is there a way I can make it so that the amount of `<li></li>` that show "fill" the width of a `<div>` class perhaps.

I'm hoping it's clear what I mean but basically at the moment the number of lights that show for my screen size is fine but upon testing the same amount on smaller screens it just spreads across way too far and  creates a scrollbar at the bottom of the browser.

```css
.lightrope {
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -23px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.lightrope li {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00f7a5;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px #00f7a5;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-1;
  animation-name: flash-1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: cyan;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-2;
  animation-name: flash-2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: #f70094;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px #f70094;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-3;
  animation-name: flash-3;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.1s;
  animation-duration: 1.1s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(odd) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.8s;
  animation-duration: 1.8s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.4s;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
}

.lightrope li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  width: 10px;
  height: 6.3333333333px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: -4.6666666667px;
  left: 1px;
}

.lightrope li:after {
  content: "";
  top: -14px;
  left: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 54px;
  height: 18.6666666667px;
  border-bottom: solid #222 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.lightrope li:last-child:after {
  width: 29px;
}

.lightrope li:first-child {
  margin-left: -40px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #00f7a5;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #00f7a5;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #00f7a5;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #00f7a5;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: cyan;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px cyan;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: cyan;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px cyan;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-3 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #DB1E31;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #DB1E31;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(219, 30, 49, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(247, 0, 148, 0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-3 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #DB1E31;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #DB1E31;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(219, 30, 49, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(247, 0, 148, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="lightrope">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Please include your code **in the question** itself, not only on an external site. See [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to replicate HTML/CSS code in a runnable fashion.

Comment: You can see the solution in the codepen itself. `.lightrope` has `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`. If you test their code on smaller screen sizes, it does not create a scrollbar.

If you've modified the code to do something else, you should share a code snippet so we can see what's actually happening.

Comment: Adding `max-width: 100%` to `.lightrope` limits the width, since `overflow: hidden` is already set.

Comment: @Damon Those parts of the code I have left intact. The code snippets in my post are what I am actually using.

Comment: @Michael It still doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do this using JavaScript like i did here:

```js
var width = document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetWidth; // get width
var lights = width / 52; // get ammount of lights (52px = one light)

for (var i = 0; i < lights; i++) {
  document.getElementById('lights').appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
  // add lights to <ul>
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.lightrope {
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -23px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.lightrope li {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00f7a5;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px #00f7a5;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-1;
  animation-name: flash-1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: cyan;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-2;
  animation-name: flash-2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: #f70094;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px #f70094;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-3;
  animation-name: flash-3;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.1s;
  animation-duration: 1.1s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(odd) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.8s;
  animation-duration: 1.8s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.4s;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
}

.lightrope li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  width: 10px;
  height: 6.3333333333px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: -4.6666666667px;
  left: 1px;
}

.lightrope li:after {
  content: "";
  top: -14px;
  left: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 54px;
  height: 18.6666666667px;
  border-bottom: solid #222 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.lightrope li:last-child:after {
  width: 29px;
}

.lightrope li:first-child {
  margin-left: -40px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #00f7a5;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #00f7a5;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #00f7a5;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #00f7a5;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: cyan;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px cyan;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: cyan;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px cyan;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-3 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #DB1E31;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #DB1E31;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(219, 30, 49, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(247, 0, 148, 0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-3 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #DB1E31;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #DB1E31;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(219, 30, 49, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(247, 0, 148, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="lightrope" id="lights"></ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I've just copied and pasted everything exactly as you put it and it doesn't seem to work for me. The lights no longer show at all. I'm putting the bit of Javascript code in to script tags which I assume is correct.

Comment: UPDATE: It works! :D I added the script part at the bottom of my source between the /body and /html tags and it now works as expected. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

`width: 100%;` was removed from the original CSS, which would fix your issue. Also note that codepen appears to use "normalize.css" under the hood, which will remove certain default styles leading to more discrepancies. For example, I've added in `margin: 0;` to `body` to prevent another horizontal scroll bar from appearing, and changed the negative margin on `.lightrope` back to its original value.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.lightrope {
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -15px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%
}

.lightrope li {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00f7a5;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px #00f7a5;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-1;
  animation-name: flash-1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: cyan;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-2;
  animation-name: flash-2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: #f70094;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 24px 3px #f70094;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash-3;
  animation-name: flash-3;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.1s;
  animation-duration: 1.1s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(odd) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.8s;
  animation-duration: 1.8s;
}

.lightrope li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.4s;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
}

.lightrope li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  width: 10px;
  height: 6.3333333333px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: -4.6666666667px;
  left: 1px;
}

.lightrope li:after {
  content: "";
  top: -14px;
  left: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 54px;
  height: 18.6666666667px;
  border-bottom: solid #222 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.lightrope li:last-child:after {
  width: 29px;
}

.lightrope li:first-child {
  margin-left: -40px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #00f7a5;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #00f7a5;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #00f7a5;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #00f7a5;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 247, 165, 0.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: cyan;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px cyan;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: cyan;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px cyan;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash-3 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #DB1E31;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #DB1E31;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(219, 30, 49, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(247, 0, 148, 0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes flash-3 {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #DB1E31;
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px #DB1E31;
  }
  50% {
    background: rgba(219, 30, 49, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 4.6666666667px 22px 3px rgba(247, 0, 148, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="lightrope">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks but strangely using that code instead, with the 'width' put back in, it actually creates a scrollbar at the bottom for me on my normal screen size as well, but if I remove the width completely it goes away.

Comment: @Sean did you also add the `margin: 0` to `body` as mentioned in my description? You have to make up for a local implementation lacking normalize.css used by codepen

Comment: Screenshot on my ultrawide: https://i.imgur.com/5kwUHk1.png
Screenshot on a smaller resolution: https://i.imgur.com/prDy1i5.png

Comment: I also added that to the body tag yep.

Comment: @sean Looks like there might be another rogue padding or margin that you have to get rid of - outside the scope of this code. It would be impossible to debug that from here. Try opening your browser devtools and check all parent elements for padding or margin.

I'm not seeing a scrollbar in your screenshots though?

Comment: If that was the case though wouldn't the scroll bars still be present even after removing all the code related to the lights?

Comment: @Sean not necessarily. Check out this fiddle for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ycurgtwa/

As you can see the absolute positioned `#b` is the problem. If you remove it, there is no horizontal scrollbar even though the `body` element has a default margin. I would have to see what the rest of the site's code looks like to help identify the problem - but you may want to try setting `position: relative` on the body or putting `.lightrope` into a relatively positioned container element

Comment: I've also found this trick helpful for visual debugging:
http://wernull.com/2013/04/debug-ghost-css-elements-causing-unwanted-scrolling/